# Launching an RDS Instance with a specified security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it possible to launch an RDS instance and associated with a specific security group?

It seems to only let me launch one that is associated with the default security group of the chosen VPC.

I can go and set the security group after the instance is started using the modify function but this is not desirable.